# Jasmine unit test cases

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to Jasmine tests and have not able been able to find a solution for this after trying many ways. Can anybody suggest a test case for this code which is in AngularJS?

```
  modalInstance.result.then(function (modalOutput) {
          if (modalOutput) {
        if ('okToUndoEdits' === modalOutput[1]) {
          $scope.chargebackDetail.cbDetails = angular.copy($scope.chargebackDetailBackup.cbDetails);
        } else if ('okToSaveUnmatched' === modalOutput[1]) {
          $('#noMatchWarning').show();
          $scope.isMatchedDoc = false;
        }
      }
    }, function () {
    });
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following test assumes that you are using angular ui bootstraps $modal. This code is untested, but should be fairly close to what you need to get started.

```
it('should revert chargebackDetail.cbDetails to the backup, if it is ok to undo edits', inject(function($modal, $q) {
  // Arrange
  $scope.chargebackDetail = {};
  $scope.chargebackDetailBackup = {cbDetails: [11, 13, 17]};

  var deferred = $q.defer();
  spyOn($modal, 'open').and.returnValue({result: deferred.promise});

  // Act
  $scope.whateverYourFunctionIsCalled();

  deferred.resolve([null, 'okToUndoEdits']);
  $scope.$apply();

  // Assert
  expect($scope.chargebackDetail.cbDetails).toEqual($scope.chargebackDetailBackup.cbDetails);
  expect($scope.chargebackDetail.cbDetails).not.toBe($scope.chargebackDetailBackup.cbDetails);
}));
```

According to your comment, you are doing the following in your test:

```
it('should get open', function() { 
  spyOn(commonService, 'openModal').and.callFake(function() { 
    return { 
      // Create a mock object using spies 
      close: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.close'),
      dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss'),
      result: { 
        then: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.result.then') 
      } 
    }; 
  }); 
  scope.open(); 
});
```

This tells me you are wrapping `$modal.open()` in a service called `commonService.openModal()`. My original test still applies, you just need to change this line:

```
spyOn($modal, 'open').and.returnValue({result: deferred.promise});
```

to this:

```
spyOn(commonService, 'openModal').and.returnValue({result: deferred.promise});
```

You also no longer need to inject $modal as I have done. If this doesn't make sense to you, you should start with more simple tests to understand testing angular with jasmine.

Comment: i was stuck entering in the line modalInstance.result.then(function (modalOutput) {  "where function(modalouput)" iam unable to cover this line

Comment: Yes, my test covers that line. `modalInstance` has a field called result, which is a promise. To test what gets wired up in that promise, you just have to spy on the `$modal.open()` call, and return your own object that has a `result` field which is a promise. You can then resolve that promise, do a `$scope.$apply`, and then assert that things happened as you expected. This is precisely what my answer shows. It takes a little while to wrap your head around testing promises in angular, but this is how it is done.

Comment: iam using phantom js

Comment: it('should get open', function() {
        spyOn(commonService, 'openModal').and.callFake(function() {
            return {                    // Create a mock object using spies
                close: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.close'),

                dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss'),
                result: {
                    then: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.result.then')
                }
            };
        });
        scope.open();
    });

Comment: the above is my test case it is covering upto modalInstance.result.then

Comment: from function(modalouput) it is not touching

Comment: Updated my answer with a line from your test - it is still relevant.

Comment: can u please help me to write test case for thi scode

Comment: $('#issueDateSpan').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#datetimepickerIssue').data('DateTimePicker').show();
});

Comment: i tried so many ways and asked many people but i couldnt able to find solution

Comment: you should ask another question since that is unrelated to this one. Also, you never upvoted my answer, or marked it correct.

Comment: i dont know recently started using it

Comment: whats the link to the other question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632316/jasmine-unit-tests-for-datetimepicker-click-event-function