# jasmine unit tests for datetimepicker click event function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Can any body suggest to write test case for this code which is in Jquery

```
  $('#issueDateSpan').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#datetimepickerIssue').data('DateTimePicker').show();
  });
```

Comment: i want to show test coverage in sonar for this function can any body suggest me i am new to angular js and jasmine

Comment: It looks jquery and has nothing to do wih angularjs. you can go through http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/js-ref/testing-dom-events-using-jquery-and-jasmine-2.0.html

Comment: i have seen it already i tried but i test coverage is not hapenning thats y i came here

Comment: what part of this is the problem? what isn't working in your test?

Comment: i should write test case for the above jquery code                                    it ("should invoke the click event.", function() {
    spyOnEvent('#issueDateSpan', 'click');
    $('#issueDateSpan').trigger( "click" );
    });

Comment: but no test coverage is happening in sonarQube dashboard